# Примитивы синхронизации пакета sync/atomic

Tags: golang, атомарность

В пакете `sync/atomic` есть объект `Once`, который позволяет потокобезопасно вызвать только один раз переданную ему в метод `Do` функцию:

```golang
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Почему нельзя использовать другую версию этого метода?

```golang
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if o.done == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Загрузка значения по указателю не гарантирована быть атомарной на всех архитектурах. Можете видеть, что [версия для 386 процессоров](https://tip.golang.org/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_386.go) действительно просто загружает указатель, в то время как [версия для 32-битных *ARM*](https://tip.golang.org/src/runtime/internal/atomic/sys_linux_arm.s) использует сложные манипуляции,